# Setup for qbasic in Windows

Tags: qbasic

How to make setup for qbasic or any basic programming language in windows system for school class?

Comment: Try downloading qb64.exe from www.qb64.org - it is a qbasic ide.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to follow the instructions on the following link.

https://www.qbasic.net/en/qbasic-downloads/DOS/Windows-Solutions.htm

Also here to download the DOS.
http://www.vmware.com/go/downloadplayer/

The process is pretty simple, give it a shot and let me know